# How to finish an activity inside onSuccess Realm callback?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I'm trying to call the `finish()` method inside the `onSuccess()` callback of a Realm transaction. The MainActivity opens another activity for the user to enter the data and create an object, this after clicking a button, my code looks something like this:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener {
  val newObject = MyObject()
  newObject.name = "Name"
  
  realmThread.executeTransactionAsync(
    { transaction -> transaction.insert(newObject) },
    { _ -> finish() }
  )

}
```

the transaction is made, but the activity doesn't close.

Comment: can you check whether you are getting callback or not?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to see that the callback was not reachable, I had to specify the OnSuccess part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to specify that I'm implementing the onSuccess callback:

```
realmThread.executeTransactionAsync(
  { transaction -> 
    transaction.insert(newObject)
  },
  Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess {
    finish()
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Make a method to call after a response from AsyncTasc and use in it finish().
I guess it doesn't work for you because you call it in a separate thread *

Comment: I tried that with my initial code, still didn't work. I'm sure that if I take your solution and apply it to the code of my answer, it would work as well.